# StreamReader with using statement difference?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, streamreader, using

I am using `StreamReader` as shown below in my code:

```
string json = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
// ... use json variable here in some other code
```

And I stumbled upon `using` statement. Is there any difference between my first statement vs using the `using` statement with `StreamReader`?

Should I be using `using` statement with `StreamReader` here in prod code?

```
        string json;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
        {
            json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Why believe us? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Comment: In regards to your particular situation `context.Request.Body` will be disposed regardless as its owned and managed by the framework. Stream reader can take a construction overload to keep the stream open, though its not really useful here. Further more, since this is likely json there are other ways to achieve this, i.e. passing the stream/body directly to a json deserializer (among others).

Comment: There's a new using syntax that might make for less broken up/nested code: `using var reader = new StreamReader(...); var json = reader.Read...`. Check it out

Comment: You can probably skip all this low level string/reader finagling  by the way and have the http request unpack your json to a class for you, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequestJsonExtensions_ReadFromJsonAsync__1_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: Although I agree that this is a question regarding `using`. I do think that this question specifically asks how to handle `using` with `HttpRequest`, thus make it more specific than the suggested duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any difference between my first statement vs using the using
> statement with StreamReader

**Yes.** The difference is that when you wrap `StreamReader` in a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement it will clear up some resources directly instead of waiting for the garbage collector. More specifically it will call `Dispose()` on `StreamReader`. You should almost always use `using` when the class implements [`IDisposable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=net-5.0).

> If your app simply uses an object that implements the IDisposable
> interface, you should call the object's IDisposable.Dispose
> implementation when you are finished using it.

Thanks to .NET Core being open source we can take a look at [the source](https://github.com/netduino/netmf/blob/master/Framework/Core/System/IO/StreamReader.cs#L66) for `StreamReader`:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (m_stream != null)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            m_stream.Close();
        }

        m_stream = null;
        m_buffer = null;
        m_curBufPos = 0;
        m_curBufLen = 0;
    }

    m_disposed = true;
}
```

As you can see it calls `Close()` on the stream, which ([according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.close?view=net-5.0)) in turn will call `Dispose()` on the stream itself.

Correctly disposing objects *can* be crucial when working with larger objects or streams. However, I will try to target your other question.

> Should I be using using statement with StreamReader here in prod code?

**Yes, no and maybe.** In your partical case you have a `context.Request.Body` as a `Stream` (which I assume is from `HttpContext`). There is no need for the `StreamReader` to close that *particular* stream. It will be disposed correctly (later) anyway. Also, there might be some other resource that need access to that particual stream later in the pipeline.

Generally, if the class implements `IDisposable` then you should wrap it in a `using`. But here I think that you have two better choices:

**1.**
If you actually have a json (as your variable suggest), you can deserialize it directly using [`JsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer?view=net-5.0) found in  `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`:

```
YourModel model = await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<YourModel>(context.Request.Body);
```

**UPDATE:** Or if you are using .NET 5 you have access to [HttpResponseJsonExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequestJsonExtensions_ReadFromJsonAsync__1_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) and can use [`ReadFromJsonAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequestJsonExtensions_ReadFromJsonAsync__1_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_System_Threading_CancellationToken_). Then you can simply try the following:

```
YourModel model = await context.Request.ReadFromJsonAsync<YourModel>();
```

Thanks to [caius-jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard).

**2.**
Use the [overload of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Boolean_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) `StreamReader` that doesn't close the stream.

```
string json;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, -1, true))
{
    json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

So, to sum up. Yes, there is a difference when using `using`. However, in your particular case you have better options.

Comment: Maybe chuck a bit in about having the request deser on your behalf - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequestJsonExtensions_ReadFromJsonAsync__1_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_System_Threading_CancellationToken_ - beats buying a dog and barking ones self !

Comment: Thanks! I actually looked for this since I knew that I used it somewhere. But couldn't find it. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/usage-and-importance-of-using-in-C-Sharp472/

In short: "using" statement ensures that managed/unmanaged resource object disposes correctly and you don't have to call "Dispose" method explicitly even there is any execeptions occured within the using block

You can read further from Microsoft official site too

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement#:~:text=The%20using%20statement%20calls%20the,t%20be%20modified%20or%20reassigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement#:%7E:text=The%20using%20statement%20calls%20the,t%20be%20modified%20or%20reassigned).